# Best practice for Ackermann car to follow a path

Tags: ros, follow-joint-trajectory, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have built a MIT-Racecar which has Ackermann and VESC.  The car can be driven with ackermann_msgs/AckermannDriveStamped type messages in ROS.

Now I would like to drive the car along a particular path to collect some videos with the camera on the car. The path consists of straight and curved segments. You can imagine the path as in a shape of "8" in a 30x30 yard region. Please note this is NOT autonomous driving. I can drive the car with teleop, an customized ROS node, etc. All I want is that the car follows the path accurately.

I am not very good in using teleop. So my first idea is to write a ROS node. I can collect some measurements of the path and calculate a serial of speed and steering parameters and let the ROS node send them out as AckermannDriveStamped message. The advantage of this method is that I can continue improve my speed/steering numbers and make the control more and more accurate. But I have two questions:

1. Is this approach the best practice to make the car follow a pre-defined path?
2. If this is the best way, is there any existing method to convert a known path to a serial of speed and steering numbers for ackermann? I think this may be a part of Path Planing, but I am not sure.

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296301/best-practice-for-ackermann-car-to-follow-a-path/) by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am also working on the predefined path problem for the navigation stack.

Here are some questions available:

[Question 1](https://answers.ros.org/question/295495/how-to-follow-a-nav_msgspath/)

[Question 2](https://answers.ros.org/question/296293/custom-global-planner-plugin-with-obstacle-avoidance/)

[Question 3](https://answers.ros.org/question/294278/custom-global-path/)

---

Originally posted by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) with karma: 135 on 2018-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-05**:
Thank you very muh

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-05**:
@aarontan could you please let me know the approach you used?

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-05**:
From Question 2, I wrote a custom global planner plugin with a predefined path, in this case a circle with a fixed radius. From the video attached with the question, you can see that my robot is able to follow this global path; however, no obstacle avoidance. You can customize the code for any path.

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-05**:
If you give me your email address, I can send you my files?

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-05**:
thank you.  userstyles at artlystyles dot com

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-06**:
i have sent you an email. if you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it as the correct one. thank you.

**Comment by [KSWang](https://answers.ros.org/users/36766/kswang/) on 2019-04-02**:
@aarontan Hi, may I get your files too. I also have the same problem.
email: rty0362@gmail.com
appreciated for your help.